# Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available. The value of this provider is derived from: - extension 'minecraft'

Tags: eclipse, minecraft

I was trying to learn minecraft modding, and the tutorial told me to use Eclipse IDE. After setting stuff up (I copied forge mdk to root folder), I was told to run gradle genEclipseRuns. Then I got error at Execute Project.afterEvaluate listener. The ,,failures" tab says:

Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available. The value of this provider is derived from: - extension 'minecraft' property 'mappingChannel'

On console it says:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'Mod'.

> Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.
> The value of this provider is derived from:
> - extension 'minecraft' property 'mappingChannel'

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

The build.gradle file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'idea'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'net.minecraftforge.gradle' version '[6.0,6.2)'
}

version = '1.0'
group = 'com.minecraft.mod'

base {
    archivesName = mod_id
}

java.toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)

println "Java: ${System.getProperty 'java.version'}, JVM: ${System.getProperty 'java.vm.version'} (${System.getProperty 'java.vendor'}), Arch: ${System.getProperty 'os.arch'}"
minecraft {
    copyIdeResources = true
    // generateRunFolders = true
    // accessTransformer = file('src/main/resources/META-INF/accesstransformer.cfg')
    
    runs {
        configureEach {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                'tutorialMod' {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        client {
            property 'forge.enabledGameTestNamespaces', 'tutorialMod'
        }

        server {
            property 'forge.enabledGameTestNamespaces', 'tutorialMod'
            args '--nogui'
        }

        gameTestServer {
            property 'forge.enabledGameTestNamespaces', 'tutorialMod'
        }

        data {
            workingDirectory project.file('run-data')

            args '--mod', mod_id, '--all', '--output', file('src/generated/resources/'), '--existing', file('src/main/resources/')
        }
    }
}

sourceSets.main.resources { srcDir 'src/generated/resources' }

repositories {
    // flatDir {
    //     dir 'libs'
    // }
}

dependencies {
    minecraft "net.minecraftforge:forge:${minecraft_version}-${forge_version}"
}

tasks.named('processResources', ProcessResources).configure {
    var replaceProperties = [
            minecraft_version: minecraft_version, minecraft_version_range: minecraft_version_range,
            forge_version: forge_version, forge_version_range: forge_version_range,
            loader_version_range: loader_version_range,
            mod_id: mod_id, mod_name: mod_name, mod_license: mod_license, mod_version: mod_version,
            mod_authors: mod_authors, mod_description: mod_description,
    ]
    inputs.properties replaceProperties

    filesMatching(['META-INF/mods.toml', 'pack.mcmeta']) {
        expand replaceProperties + [project: project]
    }
}

tasks.named('jar', Jar).configure {
    manifest {
        attributes([
                'Specification-Title'     : 'tutorialMod',
                'Specification-Vendor'    : 'Developer',
                'Specification-Version'   : '1', // We are version 1 of ourselves
                'Implementation-Title'    : project.name,
                'Implementation-Version'  : project.jar.archiveVersion,
                'Implementation-Vendor'   : mod_authors,
                'Implementation-Timestamp': new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        ])
    }

    finalizedBy 'reobfJar'
}

// tasks.named('publish').configure {
//     dependsOn 'reobfJar'
// }

publishing {
    publications {
        register('mavenJava', MavenPublication) {
            artifact jar
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "file://${project.projectDir}/mcmodsrepo"
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Also if anyone is wondering, I did everything in this tutorial until 6:42 (because it broke): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRXWa5HRAxU

**UPDATE:**
I tried going into Mod folder ( the one with all files ) typed cmd and then typed gradlew genEclipseRuns. Yet it still failed, but it gave me another error message

A problem occurred configuring root project 'Mod'.

> Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.
> The value of this provider is derived from:
> - extension 'minecraft' property 'mappingChannel'

If anyone wants stacktrace or scan, message me.